# My video share script doesn't show video thumbnails

Tags: php, image, youtube, preview

Recently I installed Video Sharing Script. There is one problem while sharing video from Youtube when I share Youtube videos the Thumbnail (preview image) doesn't appear I think something is blocking in PHP.ini. Problem is not with Script because it's working in one hosting and in another one it doesn't.

Here it is working: http://www.ihsanilim.com/media 
and  Here it is not working: http://media.islomummati.com

Both hosting is PHP 5.x and MySQL 5.x Linux Apache

Can anyone tell me what I should ON or OFF in PHP.INI to get youtube video images automatically from youtube server ...

THanks!

Comment: Forget about php.ini, that's not the cause. Open browser console and look at network tab. You see that the images are not even requested. It should be javascript issue. Maybe because the working one is under `/media/` and the other one under `/`?

Comment: yes you are right @Marek the images are not even requested ... i changed directory from http://media.islomummati.com to http://www.islomummati.com/media but it still continues ... and i don't know what to do with Javascript ... any idea?

Comment: @PoorSouh No idea, could be many things. I recomend you go again over each step of the implementation, and check if it was done correctly, and also think about potential problems.

Comment: I solved the problem FINALLY The problem was with PHP.INI like i said... SOLUTION WAS:

I changed this  
allow_url_fopen Off   

to this  
allow_url_fopen On

:D